# Compare two values for different rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of submission records with different submission times that are grouped by `id` and `sub_id`. There will be several submissions with different `sub_id` under the `id` to indicate they are the sub-events of the original event. For instance:

```
id    sub_id     submission_time       valuation_time            amend_time
G1    Original   2021-05-13T00:11:05Z  2021-05-13T00:12:05Z      
G1    Valuation  2021-05-13T06:11:05Z  2021-05-13T06:12:10Z                    
G1    Amend      2021-05-14T08:09:01Z  2021-05-14T09:09:05Z      2021-05-18T19:19:15Z
G2    Original   2021-04-12T00:11:05Z  2021-04-12T00:12:05Z      
G2    Valuation  2021-04-12T06:11:05Z  2021-04-12T06:12:10Z      
...
```

I would like to go through the dataset and examine if `valuation_time` of `sub_id == "Valuation"` is after the `submission_time` of `sub_id == "Original"` under the same `id` reference. If that is true, I would like to input a new column and populate `sub_id == "Valuation"` to be `pass`, otherwise `fail`.

I would really appreciate your help on this as I have no clue on this challenge. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please mention what you have tried and any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
import datetime
df=pd.read_excel('C:\MyCodes\samplepython.xlsx')
df['Status']=''
df_new=pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sub_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['submission_time'], "%Y-%m- 
    %dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    val_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['valuation_time'], "%Y-%m- 
    %dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    if row['sub_id']=='Valuation' and val_time>sub_time:
        row['Status']='Pass'
    elif row['sub_id']=='Valuation' and val_time<=sub_time:
        row['Status']='Fail'
    df_new=df_new.append(row)
```

Comment: thank you so much for suggesting the for-loop. I am thinking about using a for loop as well, but quick question in your solution: technically I would like to compare ```G1 - Valuation```'s ```valuation_time``` with ```G1-Original```'s ```submission time```. When we are iterating through the rows, how could we account for the comparison between two different rows?

Comment: I you can use two for loops to do this and for the if statement you can change the condition as A.Sub_id='Submission' and B.Sub_id='valuation'. I didn't try this but I hope this will work. Here A and B are data frame from first and second loop resp. Also include the id field in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

list_values=[['G1','Original',datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-05-13T00:11:05Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-05-13T00:12:05Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")], 
[< please load other values>],
['G2','Valuation',datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-04-12T06:11:05Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-04-12T06:12:10Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")]]

df=pd.DataFrame(list_values,columns = ['id', 'sub_id', 
                         'submission_time', 'valuation_time'])
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'sub_id'])
status=[]
level=0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  if level==0 and row['sub_id']=='Original': 
    sub_time=row['submission_time']
    status.append('')
    level+=1
  elif level==1 and row['sub_id']=='Valuation':
    val_time=row['valuation_time']
    if sub_time>val_time:
        status.append('Fail') 
    else:
        status.append('Pass')
    level=0
  else:
    level=0
    status.append('')
df["Status"]=status
print(df)
```

Result:
[image]